# Get a list of files and filenames without an extention using php

Tags: php, file, list

I'm trying to make a jQuery slider that automatically loads all the images in a specified folder. So I'm using a small PHP script that makes a list of all the files in that directory. For the captions of the slider I wanted to use the filename (without extension).

I'm using the following script, using PHP. It can list all the files with the extensions, but I can't find a way to also display the filename (for the captions) without the extensions.

Anyone an idea?
Thanks in advance!

```
        <? 
    $path = "img"; 
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 
    continue; 
    echo "$file"; 
    } 
    closedir($dir_handle); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 11):

Here you have more OO way:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
            $fileinfo->getBasename('.' .$fileinfo->getExtension());
        }
    }
```

Comment: aaah I just realize that getExtension() is still "No version information available, might only be in SVN", so extension needs to be  cut in other way

Comment: So can try $filename = pathinfo( $fileinfo->getPathname() , PATHINFO_FILENAME); in line 4 - as nickb sugested

Comment: `getExtension()` is available as of PHP 5.3.6. (I'll update the manual accordingly, whoops!) Secondly, the `FilesystemIterator` is preferred over the older `DirectoryIterator`.

Comment: (The [`DirectoryIterator::getExtension()`](http://php.net/directoryiterator.getextension) documentation sources have been updated. Thanks mrok.)

Answer (score 8):

You can get the filename without its extension using [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$filename = pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```